# Passing data between middleware logs correctly but returns undefined inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I'm passing data between two express middleware as one of my variables is set in a function (middleware 1) and needs to be accessed outside its function scope (in middleware 2). When I console.log req.invoice in my second middleware it logs correctly so I know that I've passed the data between the middleware correctly but when trying to use my variable to construct a new object in my second middleware the req.invoice is undefined.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Invoice = require('../models/Invoice');
var router = express.Router();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var fs = require('fs');
//Used to create a pdf invoice
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

//Route
router.route('/:item')
  .post(generateInvoice, sendMail, function(req, res){

  });

//First middleware

var fileName, dest, invoiceNr;
function generateInvoice (req, res, next) {
  //Destination for storing the invoice file
  dest = __dirname + '/../static/';
  //generate invoice nr
   Invoice.find(function(err, invoices){
    if(err) {
     return res.send(err);
    } else {
      invoiceNr = invoices.length + 1;
      fileName = 'invoice' + invoiceNr + '.pdf';
      req.invoicePath = path.resolve(dest + fileName);
      generate();
    }
  });
  //Create the invoice and store in static directory 
  function write() {
    doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest + fileName));
    doc.text(invoice, 100, 100);
    console.log('File written > ' + fileName + '\n Destination: ' + dest);
    doc.end();
  }
  function generate (err){
    if (err)
      throw err;
    if (invoiceNr !== undefined) {
      write();
    }
  }

  next();

}

//Second middleware
//I'm using mailgun-js to send the invoice via email
function sendMail(req, res, next){
  //Mailgun implementation
  var api_key = 'MY_KEY';
  var domain = 'MY_DOMAIN';
  var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
  var data = {
    from: 'APP_MAIL',
    to: 'example@mail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Should include attachment!',
    //req.invoicePath is undefined when it should be a filepath
    attachment: req.invoicePath
    //when invoicePath was set as a static string, the attachment was included in the email
    //attachment: '/Users/anton/Desktop/app/src/server/static/invoice27.pdf'
  };

  //again I'm using mailgun-js for sending the emails
  mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log('Message body: ' + body);
    //This works and I get the above: '/Users/anton/Desktop...' in the console
    console.log('The path to the invoice: ' + req.invoicePath);
    //Works properly as well
    console.log('The path is of type: ' + typeof(req.invoicePath));
  });
  res.end();
}
```

I've set req.invoicePath like this is my first Middleware.

```
req.invoicePath = path.resolve(dest + fileName);
```

A brief explanation of how to send emails with mailgun can be found on the [mailgun blog here](http://blog.mailgun.com/how-to-send-transactional-emails-in-a-nodejs-app-using-the-mailgun-api/)
Any help at all is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the first middleware and the second middleware?  Your `sendMail()` function has no output and does not modify anything so we're unsure what it is supposed to be doing?  Please show the actual code for both first middleware and second middleware.

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure to edit my question to make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asynchronous timing issues.  In your first middleware, you are calling `next()` BEFORE your `Invoice.find()` function has finished, thus executing the 2nd middleware before you set `req.invoicePath`.

To fix, call `next()` only when you are done with the asynchronous operations in the first middleware.  You also need to move your variables inside of `generateInvoice()` so they are protected local variables and will not be trounced by another request that is in flight at the same time:

```
function generateInvoice (req, res, next) {
  var fileName, dest, invoiceNr;
  //Destination for storing the invoice file
  dest = __dirname + '/../static/';
  //generate invoice nr
   Invoice.find(function(err, invoices){
    if(err) {
     return res.send(err);
    } else {
      invoiceNr = invoices.length + 1;
      fileName = 'invoice' + invoiceNr + '.pdf';
      req.invoicePath = path.resolve(dest + fileName);
      generate();
      // move next() here so it is not called until after req.invoicePath is set
      next();
    }
  });
  //Create the invoice and store in static directory 
  function write() {
    var doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest + fileName));
    doc.text(invoice, 100, 100);
    console.log('File written > ' + fileName + '\n Destination: ' + dest);
    doc.end();
  }
  function generate (err){
    if (err)
      throw err;
    if (invoiceNr !== undefined) {
      write();
    }
  }
}
```

There are potentially other asynchronous issues here too since I'm assuming that `write()` may have some async parts.  And, you show an argument to `generate()`, but you don't pass an argument.  And, if `generate()` executed the `throw err`, you don't have any handler for that to do something intelligent.

Changes I made:

1. Moved `next()` to inside the `Invoice.find()` callback so it isn't called until after `req.invoicePath` is set.
2. Moved variable declarations for `fileName, dest, invoiceNr` inside the `generateInvoice()` function so they are unique for each invocation of the function and other requests in flight at the same time will not trounce their values.

Other potential issues:

1. You declared `generate()` to accept an err parameter, yet you don't pass one to it.
2. The `throw err` in `generate()` would not be caught and do anything useful if it was ever hit.
3. You don't have any error handling on the construction of the PDF document.
4. If any of the construction of the PDF file is asynchronous, you are not waiting for it to finish before letting the next middleware attempt to use it so there could be a race condition where it isn't finished being written yet before you're trying to use it.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation and a thorough answer! This solved my problem for now. Clearly I have a lot to learn to make the code more reliable. I have cleaned up my code a bit more and removed the generate() function and now call the write() function right away instead making it easier to follow as well. However, my sendMail() function executes but now no email is being sent only the logs are happening. Of course, I'll accept your answer as it adressed my problem and I'll surely figure the other thing out. Cheers!